# Comma Separated String into a drop down in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have a comma separated string 
say 12345,67890,3453,124556,56778
and I want to display these items in a drop down list

I am working in a classic asp page.

Please help me on this

Comment: Use the _split_ function and loop through the array it creates to fill up the select options. Have fun.

Answer (score 5):

Give this a try:

```vbs
<%
' put your string into a variable.
Dim myString : myString = "12345,67890,3453,124556,56778"

' split your variable up into a array
Dim splitmystring : splitmystring = split(myString,",")

' create a dropdown box
Response.write  "<select value=""dropdown"">"
Response.write  "<option selected>choose a option</option>"

' Loop through your array
For Each item In splitmystring
    response.write "<option value='"& item &"'>"& item & "</option>"
Next

'close your dropdown box
response.write "</select>"
%>
```

Comment: It should be `value="..."` and not `name="..."` for each option.